# jquery shine effect, animate without hover as a trigger

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-effects

i am using this amazing [Jquery shine time](http://addyosmani.com/blog/shinetime/) by Addy Osmani. It works perfectly fine since all i did was copied and pasted it :D

but then i need the shine effect to automatically animate periodically as soon as the image loads without having to be hovered first, how can i achieve this ? to be honest i have almost zero knowledge when it comes to jquery and or javascript

here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*Your ShineTime Welcome Image*/
    var default_image = 'images/large/default.jpg';
    var default_caption = 'Welcome to ShineTime';

    /*Load The Default Image*/
    loadPhoto(default_image, default_caption);


    function loadPhoto($url, $caption){
        /*Image pre-loader*/
        showPreloader();
        var img = new Image();
        jQuery(img).load( function(){
            jQuery(img).hide();
            hidePreloader();
        }).attr({ "src": $url });

        $('#largephoto').css('background-image','url("' + $url + '")');
        $('#largephoto').data('caption', $caption);
    }

    /* When a thumbnail is clicked*/
    $('.thumb_container').click(function(){
        var handler = $(this).find('.large_image');
        var newsrc  = handler.attr('src');
        var newcaption  = handler.attr('rel');
        loadPhoto(newsrc, newcaption);
    });

    /*When the main photo is hovered over*/
    $('#largephoto').hover(function(){

        var currentCaption  = ($(this).data('caption'));
        var largeCaption = $(this).find('#largecaption');

        largeCaption.stop();
        largeCaption.css('opacity','0.9');
        largeCaption.find('.captionContent').html(currentCaption);
        largeCaption.fadeIn()



        largeCaption.find('.captionShine').stop();
        largeCaption.find('.captionShine').css("background-position","-550px 0"); 
        largeCaption.find('.captionShine').animate({backgroundPosition: '550px 0'},700);
    },
    function(){
        var largeCaption = $(this).find('#largecaption');
        largeCaption.find('.captionContent').html('');
        largeCaption.fadeOut();
    });

    /* When a thumbnail is hovered over*/
    $('.thumb_container').hover(function(){  
        $(this).find(".large_thumb").stop().animate({marginLeft:-7, marginTop:-7},200);
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").stop();
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").css("background-position","-99px 0"); 
        $(this).find(".large_thumb_shine").animate({backgroundPosition: '99px 0'},700);

    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(".large_thumb").stop().animate({marginLeft:0, marginTop:0},200);
    });

    function showPreloader(){
        $('#loader').css('background-image','url("images/interface/loader.gif")');
    }

    function hidePreloader(){
        $('#loader').css('background-image','url("")');
    }
});
</script>
```

Please help me, thanks

Regards

Comment: do you want it to animate on start up or periodically?

Comment: periodically, probably 3 second interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 setInterval(function() {
      $('.thumb_container').find(".large_thumb").stop().animate({marginLeft:-7, marginTop:-7},200);
        $('.thumb_container').find(".large_thumb_shine").stop();
        $('.thumb_container').find(".large_thumb_shine").css("background-position","-99px 0"); 
        $('.thumb_container').find(".large_thumb_shine").animate({backgroundPosition: '99px 0'},700);
   }, 3000);
```

Try that, or if you want to customise it, change the code where i have put all of the `$('thumb_container'`) :)

Comment: thanks man, by the way, should i just delete the .hover() function, since i dont think i need that, do i ?

Comment: I wouldnt delete anything yet, but once you've got the right code in my code, then you can delete it! I suppose as you copied and pasted the code from a blog post, if it goes tits up then you can put it all back :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the code you want to trigger in a `.hover` event helper, you can trigger that event by calling the `.hover()` function without passing any parameters.

To clarify: If you want to simulate the hover event on #largephoto, simply call this:

```
$("#largephoto").hover();
```

Comment: actually i want it to animate without having to hover, i mean as soon as the image load, the 'shine effect' began to animate periodically